# Problema con comas y columnas con CSV y PHP

Tags: php, excel, csv

estoy haciendo un CSV, Bueno ya esta terminado pero cuando me muestra los datos no se por que me muestra todos los datos en una columna y tambien cuando algun dato tiene una coma lo separa y eso hace q el dato quede como medio incompleto. como lo puedo arreglar?
este es es mi codigo

```
        if ($formato == "CSV") {
        $rutaCSV = "tmp/ReporteAuditoriaSistema-$idUsuario.csv";
        $f = fopen($spool . $rutaCSV, "w+");
        $arrayT = Array("Fecha evento", "Area auditada", "Evento", "Usuario", "Observaciones de auditoria");
        fwrite($f, "\"" . implode("\";\"", $arrayT) . "\"\n");
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataSend); $i++) {
            $arrayFila3 = array(
                "\"" . $dataSend[$i]->fecha . "\"",
                "\"" . $dataSend[$i]->nombreArea . "\"",
               "\"" .  $dataSend[$i]->nombreevento . "\"",
                "\"" . $dataSend[$i]->nombres . " " . $dataSend[$i]->apellidos . "\"",
                "\"" . $dataSend[$i]->descripcion . "\""
            );

            fwrite($f, implode(";", $arrayFila3) . "\n");
        }

        fclose($f);
    }
```

EL carácter de separación de columnas que estoy utlizando es punto y coma.

ejemplo:
Asi es como lo necesito
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero claro ese no tiene comas asi que no los separa pero este si tiene comas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca luego de empresario: hay una como y por eso el resto del texto se para laotra columna eso es lo que quiero arreglar

Comment: Los CSV suelen ser coma separated value, no punto y coma separated vale. ¿será por eso que no te lo separa en columnas? Si lo estás visualizando en excel, deberás especificar que tu carácter de separación de columnas es punto y coma `;`

Comment: sip, lo estoy viendo en excel, claro es q antes estaba de otra forma que probar con los \ para ver si aun tenia el problema con las comas.

Comment: Entonces, cual es el problema?? si usas otro caracter como separador, tenes que decirle al programa que uses para abrirlo, cual es...

Comment: podias poner un ejemplo minimo de que es lo que lees y cual es el resultado esperado?

Comment: el problema es que se se supone q todos los campos estan en una misma columna eso esta bien, pero ya que uno de esos datos o varios tienen comas los lee como si fueran para separar lo cual no es

Comment: si el campo o valor contiene el caracter usado como separador ( incluye comas ) lo encerras entre comillas. `1, "1,3", 5` si usas otro separador (`;` o espacios) lo especificas al importar o abrir el archivo

Comment: ahhhhhhh claro, no se me habia ocurrido eso, ya lo intento

Comment: pues ya revise el código y parece que todo esta bien pero sigue ocurriendo eso tal vez sea el problema sea otro, no se 
:"""(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajajja bueno, ya me funciona, parece que lo q tenia que hacer era cambiar en esta linea el ;

```
 fwrite($f, implode(";", $arrayFila3) . "\n");
```

luego de eso lo cambie por una , y ya me organizo como queria, en cada columna esta un dato, q eso era lo que tambien buscaba pero aun tengo q mirar por q con el ; no me funcionaba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda